# remove millisecond from echo time bash

Tags: bash, time, timestamp, epoch, human-readable

**1633036680022** , This is epoch result i got from elasticsearch.
if i tried to convert this epcho to human-readable date,

1. So i used [epochconverter](https://www.epochconverter.com/)
   [image]
2. And i used bash command to convert this in my terminal,

> ```
> $ date -d @1633036680022
>
> Tuesday 15 November 53718 05:30:22 PM IST
> ```

This output from terminal say the Year **53718**, because the epoch '1633036680022' is in milliseconds.

All i want is ,epoch in seconds.

Comment: `ts=1633036680022`; `date -d "@${ts%???}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide by 1000 and convert to timestamp.

```
date -d @"$(echo "1633036680022/1000" | bc)"
```

Comment: Also `date -d "@$(( 1633036680022 / 1000 ))"`.

Answer (score 1):

Strip milliseconds with `bash` (output only first 10 digits):

```
x="1633036680022"
date -d "@${x:0:10}"
```